# Visual Studio 2005 Javascript debugging

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2005

Is it possible to stop visual studio from debugging external javascript? We have a window which displays external webpage. If the page contains bad javascript then my entire session comes to a halt and breaks. Hitting continue won't move past the problem.

It's really irritating and tedious, is there an equivalent setting to "just debug my code"?

Edit : I don't want to disable javascript debugging totally, just stop it from debugging other people's crappy code..

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Check this article:

[Debugging client JavaScript in Visual Studio 2005](https://web.archive.org/web/20111231175002/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/lazydeveloper/archive/2006/07/10/84552.aspx)

Another alternative for debugging JavaScript is [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/). I think it's one of the best  and complete JS debuggers out there.